# Python - Dictionary in class not functioning as expected

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very basic class `Library`, and I initialize it with a passed in dictionary (key book name (string), value book shelf location (int)) with values already entered into it. The code looks like this:

```
class Library(object):
    def __init__(self, book_table):
        self.book_table = book_table

    def get_location(self, book_name):
        if book_name in self.book_table: # ERROR RIGHT HERE
            return self.book_table[book_name]
        else:
            return "Book Not Found"

libraries = []
libraries.append(Library({"Book1":2, "Book2":9}))
print Library(libraries[0]).get_location("Book1")
```

For some reason, I am unable to access data from the dictionary from the get_location method, but I am able to access the dictionary data in the initialize method (and I previously tested the represent method and it worked in there too). This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Programming/PyCharm/Book_Locator/Book_Locator.py", line 13, in <module>
    print Library(libraries[0]).get_location("Book1")
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Programming/PyCharm/Book_Locator/Book_Locator.py", line 6, in get_location
    book_name in self.book_table:
TypeError: argument of type 'Library' is not iterable
```

I expected it to print out Book1's location, which is a 2.

Comment: If the process of creating the example shows you what the problem was, please do us the courtesy of editing your answer to explain.

Comment: I can't post an answer while the question is still on hold, but your last line should be `print libraries[0].get_location("Book1")`. Otherwise, you are creating a new Library by passing the old Library as the `book_table` dict.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was "converting" it to type Library in order to access the Library class's methods, but I guess you don't have to do that. Once this question gets off hold, post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @itman1234: You don't have to do it because the value in that `list` is already a `Library` (that's what you `append`ed after all). FYI, for safety (catching errors like this one early, and avoiding the risk of sharing a `dict` between the `Library` and the caller so changes to the caller's `dict` change the `Library` and vice-versa), you might want to change: `self.book_table = book_table` to `self.book_table = dict(book_table)` which ensures you have a real `dict` and even if the caller passed a `dict`, shallow copies it to a fresh `dict` to decouple caller `dict` from `Library` `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a *new* `Library` instance that you pass your existing instance into:

```
print Library(libraries[0]).get_location("Book1")
#     ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
#        |        \----------- an existing instance of Library
#  A new instance of Library
```

This gives you a `Library()` instance where `book_table` is *another* `Library()` instance, not a dictionary!

You'd want to call `get_location()` *directly* on `libraries[0]`:

```
print libraries[0].get_location("Book1")
```

You could also just store *just* the `book_table` dictionary in the list:

```
libraries = [{"Book1": 2, "Book2": 9}]
print Library(libraries[0]).get_location("Book1")
```

but this would only be needed if you could not store `Library` instances in the list directly for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

`Library(libraries[0])` you call **init** again

This code should works

```
class Library(object):
    def __init__(self, book_table):
        self.book_table = book_table

    def get_location(self, book_name):
        if book_name in self.book_table:  # ERROR RIGHT HERE
            return self.book_table[book_name]
        else:
            return "Book Not Found"


libraries = []
libraries.append(Library({"Book1": 2, "Book2": 9}))

print libraries[0].get_location("Book1")
```